# g++ 4.6.1 compiler error: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-construction, assembly

I have a file which compiles without errors or warnings on my macbook pro running osx (snow leopard) using g++ (4.6.1). I just uploaded it to our linux cluster (not run by me) and tried to compile there (also using gcc 4.6.1). This time I many strange error messages with the assembler. How do I interpret the following error?

```
g++ -I../shared/boost_1_47_0 -std=c++0x -O2  -c ../shared/ft.cpp -o ../shared/ft.o

/tmp/ccEqihNa.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccEqihNa.s:809: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
/tmp/ccEqihNa.s:810: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
/tmp/ccEqihNa.s:1055: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
/tmp/ccEqihNa.s:1056: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:145: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:146: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:248: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:249: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:351: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:352: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:496: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:497: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:988: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:989: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:1488: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:1489: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:2333: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:2334: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:2460: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:2461: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:2899: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:2900: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:3053: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:3054: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:3144: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:3145: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:3205: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:3206: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:3296: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:3297: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:4090: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:4091: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:4921: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:4922: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:5094: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:5095: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:5274: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:5275: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:5365: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:5366: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:5426: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:5427: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:5525: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:5526: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:5744: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:5745: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:5919: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:5920: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:6097: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:6098: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:6209: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:6210: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:6305: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:6306: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:6735: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:6736: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:7082: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:7083: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:7355: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:7356: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:7663: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:7664: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:8139: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:8140: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:8605: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:8606: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:8894: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:8895: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:9224: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:9225: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:9531: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:9532: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:9868: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:9869: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:10313: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:10314: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:10533: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:10534: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:11052: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:11053: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:11324: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:11325: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:13561: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:13562: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:13941: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:13942: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:14340: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:14341: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:14711: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:14712: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:14862: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:14863: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:14963: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:14964: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:15381: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:15382: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:15792: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:15793: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:16293: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:16294: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:16445: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:16446: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:17045: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:17046: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:18020: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:18021: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:18111: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:18112: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:18172: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:18173: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:139: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:140: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:554: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:555: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:654: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:655: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:1344: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:1345: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:1831: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:1832: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:2522: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:2523: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:3061: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:3062: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:3284: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:3285: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:3515: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:3516: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:3745: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:3746: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:3996: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:3997: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:4518: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:4519: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:5489: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:5490: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:6382: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:6383: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:6547: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:6548: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:6651: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:6652: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:6712: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:6713: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:7146: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:7147: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:7367: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:7368: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:7597: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:7598: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:9275: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:9276: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:9562: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:9563: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:10065: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:10066: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:10326: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:10327: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:10534: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:10535: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:11978: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:11979: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:12091: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:12092: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:12936: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:12937: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:14294: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:14295: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
:16088: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'
:16089: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_lsda'
```

Comment: Show us some minimal sample code.

Comment: It might be a compatibility issue between the binutils

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The error means that your assembler (likely `/usr/bin/as`, part of binutils) is too old.

The patch that added them appears to be [this one](http://www.cygwin.com/ml/binutils/2006-11/msg00007.html). Unfortunately, the binutils NEWS file doesn't explicitly reference this addition, but since it was added in 2006, I expect any recent version of binutils would do.

Comment: Ran into the same issue: for me, the problem was not that binutils was too old, but more that I had run `./configure` on macOS, then built it, then re-ran `configure` on Linux (from the same folder) without `make clean` before. `make clean` sorted it out.

Answer (score 6):

I had this error pop up due to gcc and g++ pointing to different versions.
For any that come across this error and have recently upgraded gcc/g++ check this:

```
gcc --version
```

matches this:

```
g++ --version
```

If not you will have to review the links via

```
ls `which g++` -al
```

and

```
ls `which gcc` -al
```