# c++ / g++ - Error: Unknown pseudo-op: `. loc'

Tags: c++, gcc, configuration, g++

I am trying to configure my computer to learn C++.
I have errors and warnings once I run gcc from the terminal to call hello.cpp.

```
    C:\Users\Mathieu>gcc -g hello.cpp -o hello -lm
```

I am using a Windows computer / windows 7 (64 bits) / IDE: Sublime text or Visual Studio Code.

What I have done so far by looking for solutions in the web:

- I have added into the PATH the address of MinGW and I have added ";" before the previous PATH.
- I have also been checking all the PATH by using echo %PATH% into the terminal and checking the environmental variables.
- By typing g++ or gcc alone in the terminal, I get "fatal error, no input file", which means gcc and g++ are well detected by the computer.
- I have checked g++ and gcc versions, there are equal.

  ```
  gcc (MinGW.org GCC Build-20200227-1) 9.2.0
  gcc (MinGW.org GCC Build-20200227-1) 9.2.0
  ```
- I have also performed @alisonc recommandation found here by reviewing links.
  [g++ 4.6.1 compiler error: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cfi_personality'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872517/g-4-6-1-compiler-error-error-unknown-pseudo-op-cfi-personality)

  ```
  C:\Users\Mathieu>ls 'which g++' -al
  ls: which g++: No such file or directory

  C:\Users\Mathieu>ls 'which gcc' -al
  ls: which gcc: No such file or directory
  ```

When I have launched the program from the terminal I get a long list of errors. I am just adding 3 lines to illustrate. I am not sure if that is relevant to add everything, please, see a few ones:

```
C:\Users\Mathieu\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUFD66I.s:6498: Error: Unknown pseudo-op:
.secrel32
C:\Users\Mathieu\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUFD66I.s:153: Warning: Missing string
C:\Users\Mathieu\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUFD66I.s:153: Error: Rest of line ignored.
First ignored character is `3'.'''
```

May someone help me ?

Thank you in advance

All the best

Mathieu

Comment: Looks like a broken MinGW installation. Or maybe several conflicting ones.

Comment: Looks to me like you ran the C compiler rather than the C++ compiler.

Comment: Is it possible that you have set up for cross-compiling to a different architecture? I believe the `.s` file mentioned in the error is assembly language output from the compiler and whatever assembler that is trying to process it doesn't recognize that flavor of assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to  run:

```
g++ -g hello.cpp -o hello -lm
```

Comment: Hello Manuel, thank you for your feedback. I still have the same message issue.

Comment: As @jkb commented in the question, the failure is in the assembler, so may be the paths are incorrect or there are problems with MinGW. If you are using a Windows console, try to use MSYS terminal. If that doesn't works then there is a problem with your MinGW installation.